# How to make my code for batch label for graphs more readable and concise?

Tags: labeling

I'd like to label my graphs at once, so I write following codes.

```
chemgraph = CompleteGraph /@ Range[3];
labels := {1/2, 1/3, 1/4};
Table[chemgraph[[i]] // 
  Labeled[Graph[#, ImageSize -> 100, VertexLabels -> None], 
    Style[#, 
       20] & /@ (ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ labels)[[i]]] &, {i, 
  1, labels // Length}]
```

It can do that, but I think it is not easy to read and not beautiful  here with using Table.
Is there any way to improve?
[image]

Comment: Indeed, why aren't you using `MapThread[]`? `MapThread[Labeled[Graph[#, ImageSize -> 100, VertexLabels -> None], Style[ToString[#2, StandardForm], 20]] &, {chemgraph, labels}]`

Comment: thanks ! MapThread is better !